# How to get more info on the 400 Bad Request Error when uploading file to Azure CDN

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage

Is there a way I can find out more details about why Azure Storage rejected the message?  Some way to turn on debugging via Azure?  More details via wire shark?

This happens from `CloudFile.UploadFromStream(...)`

I've tried about 8 solutions for the **400 Bad Request** when trying to upload a file to an Azure `CDN`.  It seems like people point out issues with the code, in various ways that the error just does not express.

I've spent about 4 hours with no luck, and nothing more specific to look at.

Please note, I have not posted the code, as I am not looking for a solution to my specific issue as much as finding a solution that I can use in more situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [`StorageException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.storageexception.aspx) class, especially [`RequestInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.storageexception.requestinformation.aspx) member of that class which is of type [`RequestResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.requestresult.aspx). It contains useful information about the error.

Here's an example.

```
    static void UnderstandStorageException()
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("container");
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("something.txt");
        try
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromFile(@"D:\test.txt");
            blockBlob.AcquireLease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            blockBlob.Delete();
        }
        catch (StorageException excep)
        {
            var requestInformation = excep.RequestInformation;
            Console.WriteLine(requestInformation.HttpStatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(requestInformation.HttpStatusMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(requestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine(requestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

In this case, I am trying to acquire a lease on a blob but I am specifying 10 seconds as lease duration which is an invalid input. This will result in `400` status code from Azure Storage. When I execute the code, I get following information back:

```
HTTP Status Code: 400
HTTP Status Message: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
Storage Error Code: InvalidHeaderValue
Storage Error Message: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:04969aab-0001-001c-5965-6df5fe000000
Time:2017-01-13T06:23:25.4667820Z
```

Comment: Thank you!  That gave some immediate information I can use to improve my searches.